# Autohotkey - Copy selected text, paste in Notepad++

Tags: copy, notepad++, autohotkey, paste

I'm new to Autohotkey, tried to make a macro to:

1. Copy selection
2. Paste it in Notepad++
3. Playback Notepad++ macro (for formatting) shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
4. Copy all the edited text
5. Paste in Firefox text field

I tried starting with the following code, but I couldn't even get AHK to copy paste my selection to Notepad++.

```
^!x::

Send,  ^c

ClipWait 

IfWinExist, Notepad++

    {
    WinActivate
    Send  ^v
    }
```

Comment: Try with `SetTitleMatchMode, 2`

Answer (score 3):

Here is working script:

```
^!x::

Send, ^c

ClipWait 

SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinExist, Notepad

    {
    WinActivate
    Send, ^v
    }
    
return
```

I added command `SetTitleMatchMode, 2` as **Joe DF** mentioned in comments. That command ([link](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm)) with parameter `2` sets the matching behavior of `IfWinExist` command so that a window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match. Also added `return` in the end.